# Cordova keyboard plugin issues with screen resizing and focusing

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins, keyboard-events

I'm building a mobile application for iOS using Meteor and Cordova. I'm having trouble configuring the screen correctly when an input field is clicked on to enter information. The screen does not focus in on the input field until after something is typed on the keyboard, similar to this video: https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard/issues/62

However, in addition to this issue, clicking in the input field renders the constraints [all out of whack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2zwb.png). (Closing the keyboard makes everything fine again)

Currently I am using [cordova-plugin-keyboard](https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard). I have unsuccessfully tried cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard and ionic-plugins-keyboard. In addition to the plugin I'm using, I also have these lines of code, in accordance with [this suggestion:](https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard/issues/62#issuecomment-337952646)

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
      Keyboard.shrinkView(true)
      window.addEventListener('keyboardDidShow', function () {
        document.activeElement.scrollIntoView()
      })
    })
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated! This issue has been plaguing me for quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following - this worked for me.

run *meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-keyboard@1.2.0* command

check **cordova-plugins** containing this **cordova-plugin-keyboard@1.2.0**

include **App.setPreference('KeyboardShrinksView', true);** in **Mobile-config**

run *meteor reset*

run *meteor run ios-device --port 4000  --verbose*

check **config.xml** containing this
< preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="true"/>

> Do not manually edit the /.meteor/local/cordova-build/config.xml file,
>   as it will be regenerated at every meteor run ios/android or meteor
>   build, hence you will lose all your modifications.
>   https://riptutorial.com/meteor/example/16152/configure-your-cordova-project--config-xml-
>   https://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html

let me know if this is working on your side too.